# Tokenizer skipping blank values before the split - Java

Tags: java, token, tokenize

I used Tokenizer to split a text file which was separated like so:

FIRST NAME, MIDDLE NAME, LAST NAME

harry, rob, park

tom,,do

```
while (File.hasNext()) 
    {
        StringTokenizer strTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(File.nextLine(), ",");

        while (strTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
```

I have used this method to split it.

The problem is that when there is missing data (for example Tom does not have a middle name) it will ignore the split (,) and register the next value as the middle name.

How do I get it to register it as blank instead?

Comment: Double the comma : FIRST NAME, , LAST NAME

Comment: please post you compelete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [Davio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283166/davio)'s answer you can manage the blank and replace it with your own String :

```
String[] result = File.nextLine().split(",");
for (int x = 0; x < result.length; x++){
    if (result[x].isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Undefined");
    } else
    System.out.println(result[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split` instead.

`"tom,,do".split(",")` will yield an array with 3 elements: `tom, (blank) and do`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you have 2 solutions:

- You either double the comma in the file as suggested by [ToYonos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2003986/toyonos) OR.
- You can count the tokens before you assign the values to the variables using the countTokens() method, if there are only 2 tokens that means the person doesn't have a middle name.

Answer (score 0):

From JavaDoc of [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

> **StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility**
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality **use the split method of String**
>   or the java.util.regex package instead

So, you don't need the use of StringTokenizer.

An example with String.split

```
String name = "name, ,last name";
String[] nameParts = name.split(",");
for (String part : nameParts) {
    System.out.println("> " + part);
}
```

this produces the following output

```
> name
>  
> last name
```